# Find all anagrams in a text and print them in their original writing

Tags: java, anagram

My program reads an entire text file to a String and searches for anagrams in it.

The problem is, that it only works if I convert everything to lower case. I want to print them in their original writing.

```
try(LineNumberReader fileInputReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filePath))){
        StringBuilder inputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while((line = fileInputReader.readLine()) != null){
          inputStringBuilder.append(line);
          inputStringBuilder.append(lineSeparator);
        }

        String input = inputStringBuilder.toString();
        input = input.replaceAll("[^äÄöÖüÜßa-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
        String[] sentence = input.split(" ");

        Map<String, Set<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++){

            char[] charwords = sentence[i].toCharArray();

            Arrays.sort(charwords);

            String key =  new String(charwords);

            Set<String> anagramSet = anagrams.get(key);
            if ( anagramSet == null) {
                anagramSet = new HashSet<>();
                anagrams.put(key, anagramSet);
            }

            anagramSet.add(sentence[i]);

        }

        Collection<Set<String>> values = anagrams.values();

        for (Set<String> set : values) {
            if(set.size() > 1){
            System.out.println(set.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
            }
        }

      }
```

If there is an overall better way to execute this task, feel free to correct me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's a code review request and should be posted at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Stultuske I do have a problem though. The entire thing doesn't work anymore if I don't convert everything to lower case.

Comment: that's more a statement than a problem. S is not the same character as s, so likely that's why, but whether you write a word with uppercases or not, the word itself doesn't change, so the result remains correct. With a bit of work, that can be sorted through as well.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? This is what I'm here for.

Comment: by keeping seperate strings, for example, one of which is the original with the lowercase. you do your check on that. then you print the results by checking the id's in the orignal string.